# Node's fs.symlink() believes the link already exists; definitely doesn't

Tags: node.js, fs

I have this code:

```
// ...

var symlinkPrecommit = function (callback) {

  console.log("\n > Creating pre-commit symlink in .git/hooks/pre-commit\n");

  source = path.resolve('.git/hooks/pre-commit');
  target = path.resolve('precommit.js');

  fs.symlink(source, target, 'file', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(
        err.code === 'EEXIST' ? "Link already created!\n" : "Error\n"
      );
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (callback) callback();
  });

}

// ...
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
MaffBookPro: matt$ ./build.js

 > Creating pre-commit symlink in .git/hooks/pre-commit

Link already created!

{ [Error: EEXIST, symlink '/Users/matt/work/project/.git/hooks/pre-commit']
  errno: 47,
  code: 'EEXIST',
  path: '/Users/matt/work/project/.git/hooks/pre-commit' }
```

But when I `ls -lah` the directory in which it's trying to create the symlink, the file definitely doesn't already exist- and the permissions look completely fine:

```
MaffBookPro: matt$ ls -lah .git/hooks/
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  11 matt  staff   374B  9 Nov 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 matt  staff   510B  9 Nov 15:45 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   452B  9 Oct 12:52 applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   896B  9 Oct 12:52 commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   189B  9 Oct 12:52 post-update.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   398B  9 Oct 12:52 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   1.6K  9 Oct 12:52 pre-commit.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   1.3K  9 Oct 12:52 pre-push.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   4.8K  9 Oct 12:52 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   1.2K  9 Oct 12:52 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 matt  staff   3.5K  9 Oct 12:52 update.sample
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

This was counter-intuitive to me as I imagined src -> dst, but in :
`fs.symlink(srcpath, dstpath[, type], callback)`

- `srcpath` is what the link is pointing to
- `dstpath` is where the new link will be created

It is named in the same way as the unix `ln` command, and its easier to remember if you don't think about the link being constructed but instead remember it has the same interface as `cp`, where the source is the existing file and the destination is where the new file will be created.